# Getting details from vue component in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuex

[image: Screenshot of my vue components]

I have a Laravel 5.4 project.

I have created two components : Students.vue and Student.vue component
Students.vue get all the students and Student.vue the markup for one display of a student
here is my Students.vue

```
    <template> 

        <div v-if = "students.length && meta">


              <pages :pagination = "meta"></pages>

              <div class = "col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-4 music_genre" v-for = "student in students">

                 <student :student = "student"></student>

              </div>

      </div> 

    </template>

    <script>

    import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    import eventHub from '../../events.js'


        export default {

            methods: {

                ...mapActions({

                    getStudents: 'student/getStudents'
                })
            },

            computed : {

              ...mapGetters ({

                students : 'student/students',

                meta : 'student/meta'
              })

            },

            mounted() {

               this.getStudents(1)
            }
        }
    </script>

here is my Student.vue

    <template>
      <div class="">

          <div class="team-info ">

              <h4>
                <a href="#">

                  {{student.name}} {{student.last_name}}

                </a>

              </h4>

            <span class='team-member-edit'>

              <a href="#"><i class='fa fa-pencil icon-xs'></i></a>

            </span>

          </div>
            <p>Along with studies, is good in all around activities held in the university events.</p>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>

        export default {

          props:['student'],


            mounted() {


            }
        }
    </script>
```

When i click on the Student Name, I would like to display all the details of the student. How to achieve that

Comment: Where do you want to display the details? In a new comonent or in the same student.vue component.

Comment: I have created a new component StudentDetails.vue but what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a key differentiating each students, hence you can do this

```
    '/students/:id': {
    component: 'student'
}
```

Comment: That would mean I will use Vue-router. But I have no idea where I should place <router-view></router-view>

Comment: I want to receive the props from the students component and display the details of each student on the student component. How to pass props using view-router

Comment: you can use $emit through the event bus https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html